# How will I use Nginx + Slim on Windows running in /api/?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, nginx, slim

Edited because it now works:
check the code below.

I have a fully environment working with **Debian 7** + **Nginx** + **Slim** + PHP + MySQL
The structure is like this:

- root
- |---- api
- |---- app
- |--- ....
- |--- docs

etc

I have index.html at the root and then index.php at the /api subdir

I have routes working well at linux debian.
Everything is working in Linux.

Now...
I had to get it working as well in windows. (yes, I know... don't)

So I have a local domain called agil.windows.ft (which is set at my hosts file in windows)

I got all my nginx/mysql/php working on my windows 8.1 machine
And I setted up the website with the same structure.

In debian the root is at  /home/development/[siteroot]
In windows it is in c:\WebSites[siteroot]

I can run the website and I CAN go to

agil.windows.ft/api/   and get a response (check the end of the post, please)

BUT I am not being able to call, for example

agil.windows.ft/api/info   (which is routed to show phpinfo() )

```
$onapp->get('/info', function(){
    phpinfo();
});
```

as it **returns a 404 error**

My DEBIAN agil config file in NGINX is:

```
server {
listen          80; ## listen for ipv4
server_name     agil.debian.ft;
root            /home/developing/agil;

access_log      /var/log/www/agil.access.log;
error_log       /var/log/www/agil.error.log;

index           index.html index.php;

## Support for favicon. Return a 204 (No Content) if the favicon
## doesn't exist.
location = /favicon.ico {
        try_files /assets/img/favicon.ico =204;
}

//COMMENTED THE FOLLOWING LINE
**#try_files /api/$uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$request_uri;**
// AND IT WORKS

location /api/ {
    try_files /api/index.php =404;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000; 
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^/api/(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
}
```

}

and the one I have now, after trying and trying in **windows** **NGINX** is:

```
server {
listen          80; ## listen for ipv4
server_name     agil.windows.ft;
root            c:\WebSites\agil;    
access_log      logs/agil.access.log;
error_log       logs/agil.error.log;

index           index.html index.php;

## Support for favicon. Return a 204 (No Content) if the favicon
## doesn't exist.
location = /favicon.ico {
        try_files /assets/img/favicon.ico =204;
}

#try_files /api/$uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$request_uri;

location /api/ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        try_files /$uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/api/(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
}
```

}

well...

Bottom line:

Can anyone help?

*Thank you very much*

***FT***

---

The result for agil.windows.ft is:

```
API 1.0 - B2B

Agil V1Slim\Environment Object

(

    [properties:protected] => Array

        (

            [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET

            [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1

            [SCRIPT_NAME] => /api

            [PATH_INFO] => /

            [QUERY_STRING] => 

            [SERVER_NAME] => agil.windows.ft

            [SERVER_PORT] => 80
            [COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=7pqv1re0pgd2m5lu412a1ejb74
            [ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => pt-PT,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
            [ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, sdch
            [USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
            [ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
            [CONNECTION] => keep-alive
            [HOST] => agil.windows.ft
            [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 
            [CONTENT_TYPE] => 
            [slim.url_scheme] => http
            [slim.input] => 
            [slim.errors] => Resource id #20
            [slim.log] => Slim\Log Object
                (
                    [writer:protected] => Slim\LogWriter Object
                        (
                            [resource:protected] => Resource id #20
                        )
                        [enabled:protected] => 1
                    [level:protected] => 4
                )
            [ApiDir] => C:\Websites\Agil/api
```

Comment: Try "root            c:/WebSites/agil; ", what do the logfiles say about this 404? +disable the try_files in /api/ and see what happens.

Comment: Hello all.

Thanks itpp13, for the tip.
I tried that but had no success.

I ended up by disabling try files OUTSIDE of /api/ location


And /api/info  worked.


BUT.... all other in the included route files didn't ...

like /api/reports/summary that should be defined in a different PHP file.

But THAT was because of DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

So... all work fine now.


Thanks